# Problem with recursion in Python: Kernel Crash

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to read data from a list, but there are some inconsistencies. So I want to store only the data which shows periodicity, assuming all the inconsistencies have the same format.

We expect each 12 items a datetime object, but for some days there are less data, and I am not interested in those dates (for simplicity sake). When a date has missing data I think it only has 6 elements instead of 11. Days and all data are items of a list. So I'm trying to store the index of the dates which don't follow the described pattern (for the next date, the element we are seeing shouldn't be a date)

I'm trying to do this using recursion, but every time I run the function I have created, the kernel restarts.

I cannot link the data of clean_values because AEMET opendata eliminates the data requested after like five minutes

```
import datetime as dt

tbe=[]

def recursive(x, clean_values):
    if x<len(clean_values) and x>=0:
        for i in range(0,len(clean_values),12): 
            if type(clean_values[i]) == dt.datetime: #If it is not a datetime
                pass
            else:
                tbe.append(i-12) #We store the date before (that should be the one with the problem)
                break    
            recursive(i-6, clean_values) # And restore the function but using the position in which we think the date is 
    else:
        return
recursive(0, clean_values)
```

Sorry I cannot provide more information

Comment: If the data is too big, maybe you're running out of memory?

Comment: Python doesn't have tail-call optimization. Don't use recursion for this.

Comment: Your description of the data structure you are using is very confusing. It would be easier if you made a small example dataset of fictional data and pointed out the things you wanted from it. I say this because I share the opinion of other commenters that recursion is unnecessary for what it seems you are trying to do